# Rendering Tilemap Tile Layer Side by Side for Infinite/Endless Runner Game

Tags: libgdx, box2d, tilemap, side-scroller

I was strugeling this for days how to implement tilemap into libgdx and box2d with infinite/endless scheme. I can load a single map and display everything on screen. But placing 2 or more tilemap side by side got me headache. I know currently not possible to offset/add x value position of tilemap. What I do right now is use setview for camera of it's render method. This is my map helper and currently I works with 3 renderer for 3 tilemap as a test...

```
public class MapHelper {
private Array<OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer> renderer = new Array<OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer>();
private int number;
private float oldDistance, currentDistance;
private String layer = "world";

public MapHelper(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    number = 0;
    item = new ItemMap[3];
}

public void render(CamHandler cam) {
    for(int r = 0; r < renderer.size; r++) {
        if(item[r] != null) {
            renderer.get(r).setView(cam.getCam().combined, item[r].distance, 0, item[r].getWidth(), item[r].getHeight());
            renderer.get(r).render();
        }
    }
}

public void updateMap(CamHandler cam) {
    if(mapOut(cam)) {
        number++;
        if(number > 2)
            number = 0;
        loadMap(number);
    }
}

/**
 * Check if camera reach the current distance, then build new map
 * @param cam
 * @return
 */
private boolean mapOut(CamHandler cam) {
    float x = cam.getCam().position.x + cam.getCam().viewportWidth / 2;
    Utils.log("pos cam x "+x+" current distance "+currentDistance);
    return x >= currentDistance;
}

private void loadMap(int map) {
    AssetsManager.loadMap(map);
    if(item[map] != null) {
        renderer.set(map, new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(AssetsManager.map));
        item[map].set(TileHelper.getMapWidth(AssetsManager.map, layer), TileHelper.getMapHeight(AssetsManager.map, layer), currentDistance);
    } else {
        renderer.add(new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(AssetsManager.map));
        item[map] = new ItemMap(TileHelper.getMapWidth(AssetsManager.map, layer), TileHelper.getMapHeight(AssetsManager.map, layer), currentDistance);
    }

    oldDistance = currentDistance;
    currentDistance += TileHelper.getMapWidth(AssetsManager.map, layer);
    callback.onLoad();
    Utils.log("load new map "+map+" distance "+currentDistance);
}

public Array<OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer> getRenderer() {
    return renderer;
}

public Array<Body> getBodies(World world) {
    return new MapBodyBuilder().buildShapes(AssetsManager.map, world, oldDistance);
}

private ItemMap[] item;

private class ItemMap {
    private float distance, mapWidth, mapHeight;

    ItemMap(float w, float h, float distance) {
        mapWidth = w;
        mapHeight = h;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    private void set(float mapWidth, float mapHeight, float distance) {
        this.mapWidth = mapWidth;
        this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    private float getWidth() {
        return mapWidth * Constants.WORLD_TO_SCREEN;
    }

    private float getHeight() {
        return mapHeight * Constants.WORLD_TO_SCREEN;
    }
}

private Callback callback;

public interface Callback {
    void onLoad();
}

public void startOver() {
    clear();
    currentDistance = number = 0;
    loadMap(number);
}

private void clear() {
    for (OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer render : renderer) {
        render.dispose();
    }
}
```

}

With above class, I can display and load new map on screen when camera reaching the map end. But the tile layer texture keeps wrong position. Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand right , you missed to check this.

- if, your *MAP_PIECE* is 2nd you must add(if moving right) previous
  *MAP_PIECE's* width
- if, your *MAP_PIECE* is 3rd you must add *MAP_PIECE's* width x2
- if, your *MAP_PIECE* is 3rd you must add *MAP_PIECE's* width x3

For example you can have variable like *delta/difference* or something.

```
difference = 0,
```

each time you load new "map/chunk" you just:

```
difference += map's width
```

and each time you draw add *differecne* to map's position on x_axis

Below is your code (not fixed, just copy-past) i think it could be integrated here

```
if(item[map] != null) {
        renderer.set(map, new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(AssetsManager.map));
        item[map].set(TileHelper.getMapWidth(AssetsManager.map, layer), TileHelper.getMapHeight(AssetsManager.map, layer), currentDistance);
    } else {
        renderer.add(new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(AssetsManager.map));
        item[map] = new ItemMap(TileHelper.getMapWidth(AssetsManager.map, layer), TileHelper.getMapHeight(AssetsManager.map, layer), currentDistance);
    }
```

Comment: thankyou for advice.
Yes, i have this method on code above, there is a currentDistance which hold current X axis. I had custom ItemMap class that store width, height, and distance for each 3 maps. So during build map, CurrentDistance will be updated just after new map being loaded.

Comment: @NinoFrenn If you are the owner of the account that posted the question, I suggest you visit [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged. This will allow you to post comments on the answers here.